# How do I apply the "outline" CSS property with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

Typically, for styles that have to be applied dynamically to HTML objects with JS, we set it as an attribute using "setAttribute()"

What about this "[outline](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)" CSS property? How can I set that onto an object with JS? Unless there is a way to dynamically add CSS to the document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change most CSS values using the following code:

```
document.getElementById('idofelement').style.outline='value';
```

or

```
object.style.cssproperty='value';
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_outline-style.asp) is what W3 has to say about it.

Comment: Oh its a value of the "style" attribute! ... style="outline:none;"

Comment: I guess that would be the HTML equivalent, yeah.